# Count the version numbers owned by customers

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that stores the sales of software to our customers. A customer can appear in the table multiple times due to upgrades.

```
Cust ID    Version
-------    -------
0          5
1          5
2          6
3          6
4          6.5
1          7
4          7
5          7
```

I want to find the counts of the latest version number that customers own. I.e., given the above data:

- 3 customers (#1, #4, #5) own version 7.
- 2 customers (#2, #3) own version 6.
- 1 customer (#0) owns version 5.

I don't need to know the customer IDs, just the count for each version.

FWIW, I'm SQL-querying an Access table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a query which shows you the maximum `Version` for each customer.

```sql
SELECT
    y.[Cust ID],
    Max(y.Version) AS MaxOfVersion
FROM YourTable AS y
GROUP BY y.[Cust ID];
```

Create another query which uses the first one as a subquery.  In that new query, count the number of rows for each `Version` grouping.

```sql
SELECT
    sub.MaxOfVersion AS [Version],
    Count(*) AS [CountOfVersion]
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            y.[Cust ID],
            Max(y.Version) AS MaxOfVersion
        FROM YourTable AS y
        GROUP BY y.[Cust ID]
    ) AS sub
GROUP BY sub.MaxOfVersion;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you HansUp!